# Не отображается блок

Tags: html, css

```css
.block4  {
width: 70px;
height: 40px;
position: absolute;

}
```

```html
<div class="block4" style=background-image: url("123.jpg") alt="image-1"></div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Кавычки соблюдайте. И картинка должна быть.

Comment: Картинка есть, где кавычки я забыл. В style поставил

Comment: Теги оборачивают в кавычки: `style="background-image: url('123.jpg')"`.

Comment: Спасибо большое.